# How to find an exact match using regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, routes, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have some problems when trying to make a match with my URL with my regex pattern in PHP.

my regex:

`/article/([0-9A-Za-z]++)/post/([0-9A-Za-z-_]++)`

```
public function matches(Route $route){
    $uri = filter_var(strip_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    if (preg_match('#' . "/article/([0-9A-Za-z]++)/post/([0-9A-Za-z-_]++)" . '#i', $uri, $this->matches)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**example 1:** VALID MATCH (good)

```
/article/AB545455DSAF54FSA45S4F4/post/FGFG-FGFGF-5FG54FGF-FGFGFG
```

**but also matches this** (bad):

```
/article/AB545455DSAF54FSA45S4F4/post/FGFG-FGFGF-5FG54FGF-FGFGFG/fgfg/fgfgfg/fgf
```

I want only to match the first example, so how do i fix this? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a terminating anchor to your regex:

```
/article/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/post/([0-9A-Za-z-_]+)$
                                             ^^^
```

The anchor will ensure that no more subdirectories can appear after the final component.

```
public function matches(Route $route){
    $uri = filter_var(strip_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    if (preg_match('~/article/[0-9A-Za-z]+/post/[0-9A-Za-z_-]+$~", $this->matches)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that matching something in regex one or more times uses a single plus, not two of them.

I may not have your exact code working here, but the pattern I suggest appears to work in the demo below.

### Demo

Comment: that's awesome, thanks for the advice. i use ++ because I saw code on github that used it too `protected $match_types = array(
  'i'  => '[0-9]++',
  'a'  => '[0-9A-Za-z]++',
  'h'  => '[0-9A-Fa-f]++',
  's'  => '[0-9A-Za-z-_]++',
  '*'  => '.+?',
  '**' => '.++',
  ''   => '[^/\.]++'
 );`

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : I was thinking you as a database guy :)

Comment: thanks for the Demo, now it works perfectly, here is the complete code: https://github.com/Jlopez2045/SimpleRouter/blob/master/router/router.php

Comment: @sumit I'm a Stack omnivore.  If it has a heartbeat, I'll eat it :-)

Comment: @Tim please change the delimiter to avoid the in-pattern escaping.  Also, please move the hyphen to the front or back of the character class so that a range is not created.  Finally, the capture groups are not necessary.

Comment: @mickmackusa Let me know if I omitted anything.  Didn't know that hyphen could also start a character class, +1 to your comment.

Comment: Just the pattern delimiters.  I would probably go with `~`.  Then you can "un-escape" the `/`s in the pattern.  `~/article/[0-9A-Za-z]+/post/[0-9A-Za-z_-]+$~`  And now that I think about it `\w` would be well placed in this pattern for brevity.  https://regex101.com/r/Ty1jVf/1

Comment: Hmm. I just learned something.  `[0-9A-Za-z-_]` actually wasn't generating a range of characters because it immediately followed a range of characters.  Thanks for updating anyhow.

Comment: Yeah...it was working in the demo (well...at least a very similar pattern was working in the demo).  Yay for PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys helped me a lot. then I will use this regexp 
 `~/?article/[0-9A-Za-z]+/post/[\w-]+/?$~i `